# How to get the Cost of Azure Managed Disk based on the VM Size using powershell or API?

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api, azure-managed-disk, azure-billing

I am looking for a PowerShell cmdlet or API, which can give me the cost of the Managed Disk as we can see from the Azure Portal

Comment: Could you please provide a sample image/

Comment: How's going ? Has your issue got solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [Azure cost management query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage) to get the real cost of your Managed Disks.

On Azure Poral:
[image]

The request of API calling :
[image]
You can also use [QueryFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage#querydataset) in query dataset to get the result you need directly.

Result:
[image]

You can also Azure PowerShell to do this. Details see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.costmanagement/invoke-azcostmanagementquery?view=azps-5.3.0).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am looking for an API to gives me the estimate of cost/month upon selection of VMSize, as we see it in the Azure Portal upfront before procuring the VM

Comment: As far as I know, the API that estimate of cost/month for a VM is not a public one. So if you want to finish this kind of things, you need to calculate the cost yourself by code. Basically, we could get the Azure billing rate list by this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/usage-rate-card-overview#azure-resource-ratecard-api-preview and calculate the cost:30*24hours* vm prcice for each hour

Comment: @KrishnaAvinashChunduru, if my post is helpful,please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query . If you have any more questions, just open a new question and let me know the link :)

Comment: @KrishnaAvinashChunduru, how's going ? Has your issue got solved?